# Percentage stacked bar chart pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing totals for various groups, and I would like to plot the total of all the groups, but coloured by group (to visualise how much each group contributes to the total).

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'Group': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                 'total': [20.0, 5.0, 30.0, 2.0, 21.0]})
```

I have tried using

```
pd.crosstab(data.Group, data.total).plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

and

```
data['cumsum'] = data['total'].cumsum()
data['cumsum'].plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

and

```
data.pivot_table(values=['total'], 
                  index='Group',
                  aggfunc='sum').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

But none of these is doing what I want - which is a single bar with the totals of each group stacked on each other and coloured by group.

Comment: Would a pie chart looks better?

Comment: No, because it wouldn't have the amounts on the x-axis.

Comment: Try `data.set_index('Group').T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.T.loc[['cumsum']].plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the nicest way but:

```
pd.concat([data[['total']],data[['total']]],axis=1).transpose().plot.area()
```

@Quang Hoang's solution is definately better...